# extjs 5 XTemplate evaluation exception: validTypes is not defined

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd

Error appear on ExtJS 5 when I create a simple window:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{title: 'Simple Title',
height: 500,
width: 500,
                            autoShow: true})
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit: trying to create the project with minimum files: *ext-all.js* and *ext-theme-neptune-all.css*

Comment: Can you provide the error you are receiving in the console? When i try out your code in [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6pq) it works as expected, so more info would help.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a part of Sencha Cmd generated app then make sure that you don't get any "Synchronous Warning" while developing and then:

```
sencha app refresh
```

and if it doesn't help

```
sencha app build
```

Comment: I am trying to add ext-all to existing project with rails, that runs extjs4